# How to send email to particular person on submit button click using php and imap?

Tags: javascript, php, email, email-attachments, gmail-imap

I used gmail imap function to get all my emails, and saved my all emails to database. my all the attachments to a folder name attachment. it all runs successfully. now i want to send email to a particular user on submit button click. and i want when i click on send button, the row against the send button email will send to the user i mentioned in To:-. and if the email has any attachment the attachment also sent to user. i used a code, but it did not work.

please help

```
    <h1 align="center">Gmail Email Inbox using PHP with IMAP</h1>
    <?php
        include('header.php');
        if (! function_exists('imap_open'))
        {
            echo "IMAP is not configured.";
            exit();
        } else {
            ?>
    <div id="listData" class="list-form-container">
        <?php
    
    // include_once('lib/class.imap.php');
    
    // $email = new Imap();
    $connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX','myemail@gmail.com','mypassword');

            $emailData = imap_search($connection, 'All');       
            if (! empty($emailData)) {
                ?>
                    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped  mail">
                <thead>
                <tr class="justify-content-center">
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th> Action </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <?php
            $one="";
            $two="";
            foreach ($emailData as $emailIdent) {
                    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($connection, $emailIdent, 0);
                    $message = imap_fetchbody($connection, $emailIdent,'1'); 
                    // $attachment = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $emailIdent, '8');              
                    $partialMessage = trim(quoted_printable_decode($message));
                    $date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($overview[0]->date));
                            ?>
                            <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td><span class="column">
                                <?php echo $overview[0]->from; 
                                $one = $overview[0]->from;
                                ?>
                        </span></td>
                        <td class="content-div"> <span class="column">
                                <?php echo $overview[0]->subject; 
                                    $two = $overview[0]->subject;
                                ?>  </td>
                        </span>  <td> <span class="date">
                                <?php echo $date; ?>
                        </span> </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="sendmail" /> 
                                    </td>
                        <!-- <td class="column">
                            <?php print_r($message); ?>
                        </td> -->
                    </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    <?php
    
                    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $emailIdent);  
                    $attachments = array();
                    
                    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
                    {
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
                    {
                    $attachments[$i] = array(
                        'is_attachment' => false,
                        'filename' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                        'attachment' => ''
                    );
    
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                    {
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                        {
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                    {
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                        {
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $emailIdent, $i+1);
    
                        /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                        if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                        { 
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                        /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                        elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                        { 
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                $filename="";
            foreach($attachments as $attachment)
            {
                if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
                {
                    $filename = $attachment['name'];
                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
    
                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";
                    $folder = "attachment";
                    if(!is_dir($folder))
                    {
                         mkdir($folder);
                    }
                    $fp = fopen("./". $folder ."/". $emailIdent . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                    fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                    fclose($fp);
                }
            }
    
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "email";
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }   
    
                $query= "insert into access (sender,date,subject,body,attachments) values ('$one','$date','$two','$message','$filename')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            }
                        if(isset($_POST['sendmail'])) 
                        {
                           $one;
                           $date;
                           $two;
                           $message;
                           $filename;
    
                           $email_to = "senderemail@gmail.com";
                           $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                           $header.= 'From: NAME <parteek.gwebs@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
                           $header.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                           $header.= 'X-Priority: 3 \r\n';
    
                           mail($email_to,$one,$two,$message,$filename,$headers);
                        }
    
              // End foreach
                ?>
        </table>
            </div>
        <?php
            }         
            // end if        
            imap_close($connection);
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () 
        {
        $('.mail').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: When sending emails from Gmail, you should send them through their SMTP server. This will be much easier to do if you use a tried and tested mail library like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer instead of the low level `mail()`-function. If you don't use their SMTP, a lot of mail server will reject the email since it doesn't come from a proper gmail server and it will be considered a spoof

Comment: You should also expand on what "not working" means, as it can mean anything.

Comment: If you used imap to get the emails, then it might make sense to use imap to send them as well, then they'll come from the right mailbox. or you could use SMTP as suggested. Sending from your own mailserver via mail() is not a good approach in this situation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on ` i used a code, but it did not work.`?